# mvc2 Html.label("mystring") mangling

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Given the MVC2 code below why is the second label getting mangled?

```
<%=Html.Label("DisplayFor(" + "DateHired,\"Date\"):") %>
<%=Html.Label("DisplayFor(" + "c=>c." + "DateHired,\"Date\"):") %>
<%=Html.DisplayFor(c=>c.DateHired,"Date") %>
```

results in:

DisplayFor(DateHired,"Date"):

DateHired,"Date"):

2/28/1999

Comment: Why the concantenation? If you have replaced variables with values can you let us know what the underlying types are? If that is the case, it is the types that will help us to help you :)

Comment: concatenation not necessary:
can be Html.Label("DisplayFor(c=>c.DateHired,\"Date\"):")
it's like Html.Label is trying to eval the lambda.
the ViewModel passed in is customer with property of DateHired.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is simply that you cannot use ">" in the text of HTML as it thinks it is markup.

instead use `&gt;`

i.e.

```
<%=Html.Label("DisplayFor(" + "c=&gt;c." + "DateHired,\"Date\"):") %>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me:
<%=Html.Label("DisplayFor(c=&gt;c.DateHired,\"Date\"):") %>
results in:
DateHired,"Date"):